# Eclipse Not working with java 8 and win 8

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to run `ecipse` it shows this error message. I installed `java 8` and uninstalled `java 7`. `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6` this is the difference, because I have tried that also its not working for me.

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash C:\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0.v20140925-0400\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140603-1326\eclipse_1603.dll
-startup C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 1b34_90
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar C:\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
```

Any body have any idea what this error means.

Comment: maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18061444/3111870

Comment: You have a 32 bit Eclipse and a 64 bit Java, they must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

open file

> `eclipse.ini`

and add two lines below `opnFile` and above `-vmargs` commend in `eclipse.ini`

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin
```

where `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin` path is your JDK bin directory path